# XNA: Getting a struct as a texture to the GPU

Tags: c#, graphics, directx, xna, texture2d

I use XNA as a nice easy basis for some graphics processing I'm doing on the CPU, because it already provides a lot of the things I need. Currently, my "rendertarget" is an array of a custom Color `struct` I've written that consists of three floating point fields: R, G, B.

When I want to render this on screen, I manually convert this array to the Color `struct` that XNA provides (only 8 bits of precision per channel) by simply clamping the result within the byte range of 0-255. I then set this new array as the data of a `Texture2D` (it has a `SurfaceFormat` of `SurfaceFormat.Color`) and render the texture with a `SpriteBatch`.

What I'm looking for is a way to get rid of this translation process on the CPU and simply send my backbuffer directly to the GPU as some sort of texture, where I want to do some basic post-processing. And I really need a bit more precision than 8 bits there (not necessarily 32-bits, but since what I'm doing isn't GPU intensive, it can't hurt I guess).

How would I go about doing this?

I figured that if I gave Color an explicit size of 32 bytes (so 8 bytes padding, because my three channels only fill 24 bits) through `StructLayout` and set the `SurfaceFormat` of the texture that is rendered with the `SpriteBatch` to `SurfaceFormat.Vector4` (32 bytes large) and filled the texture with `SetData<Color>` that it would maybe work. But I get this exception:

> The type you are using for T in this method is an invalid size for this resource.

Is it possible to use any arbitrarily made up `struct` and interpret it as texture data in the GPU like you can with vertices through `VertexDeclaration` by specifying how it's laid out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have what I want by dumping the Color `struct` I made and using `Vector4` for my color information. This works if the `SurfaceFormat` of the texture is also set to `Vector4`.